# How to insert UTC datetime in SQLAlchemy/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Javascript code will treat timestamps as utc and convert to local timezone when using `new Date()`. Problem is the timestamps are already local time while in the database, so now I want to convert the timestamps to utc time when inserting to solve this problem. How can this be done with SQLAlchemy?

Timestamp:

```
2015-04-12T04:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Date(Date.UTC(...))` instead of `new Date()`

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date